# Solaris support for ext4/ext3/btrfs

Tags: filesystems, solaris, ext3, ext4, btrfs

Does anyone know if Solaris 11 (Sparc version) supports mounting ext3/ext4 or even better Btrfs volumes ?

Most of the topics I find on the web are quite outdated (2006/2007) and reference old versions of Solaris which were pretty unfriendly to Linux oriented FS.

I was hoping that the situation changed, so if you have any info or pointers, I'd really appreciate.

Thanks per advance,

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/pradhap/entry/mount_ntfs_ext2_ext3_in

Comment: Thanks, are the Sparc packages available as well ?

Comment: I've no idea. Discover someone's using Google.

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box - you'd have to find add-on filesystem modules, like those referenced in the comments.